# Unwanted Space Between Vertical Bar and Math Operator

Tags: spacing, math-operators

In my preamble, I have defined a math operator by writing `\DeclareMathOperator{\Av}{Av}`. When I use the command `$\Av$`, there is a small amount of horizontal space on each side of the operator. Usually, this spacing looks good, but not when I put it inside absolute value symbols. For example, if I write `$|\Av(n)|$`, then there is a little vertical space between the first vertical bar and the A. Is there a way to define my operator in my preamble so that this spacing does not appear?

Comment: never use |  for abs,  use `\lvert A \rvert`, they all use the same symbol but with the right math class so TeX can get the spacing right.

Comment: Therefore, use `$\lvert\Av(n)\rvert$`

Comment: Another reason why you should never use `|` from the keyboard can be seen here: `$|-1|$`, wrong spacing. I'd recommend defining an `\abs` macro using the mathtools package, I think it is even listed in the manual how to define it using mathtools

Answer (score 1):

The comments already gave you a couple of good solutions, `\lvert \Av(n) \rvert` and defining an `\abs` command using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from [`mathtools`.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#subsection.3.6)

The reason you’re having this problem is the spacing between atoms of different math classes.  A command you define with `\declaremathoperator` has the same `\mathop` spacing as log or sin, so if you try to bracket it with two `\mathord` atoms, you’ll get spacing like 2 log x.  You instead want your delimiters to have `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` spacing, like `(` and `)` or `[` and `]`, and `\lvert` and `\rvert` do.