# What is the correct spacing for an operator inside vertical bars?

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I have recently learned from questions like

[Unwanted Space Between Vertical Bar and Math Operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590963/unwanted-space-between-vertical-bar-and-math-operator)

that we should write

```
\lvert \sin(x) \rvert
```

instead of

```
| \sin(x) |
```

for denoting the absolute value of a quantity. However, the visual appearance of the latter approach does not seem to be perfect:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\[
|\sin(x)|
\]

\[
\lvert \sin(x) \rvert
\]


\end{document}
```

[image: Comparing |sin(x)| and \lvert \sin(x) \rvert]

When comparing with the space between ")" and "|" the former has too much space between "|" and "s", while the latter seems to have slightly too little space between "|" and "s".  In other words, the sin(x) term does not appear to be set in the centre of the two vertical bars in either case.

1. How can the appearance be improved?
2. Is there any good reason why it shouldn't be changed?

Comment: The latter is correct. What you see is from the design of the `()`. If you set `\fboxsep=0pt` and then do `\boxed{)}` you'll see that `)` it self leaves space after it. Noone else have complained about it.

Comment: For all we know the answer to question 2 might be "Knuth insist on backward compatibility" like the descender in [italic 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627317/why-is-the-7-computer-modern-italic-jumping-out-of-the-baseline-in-this-code)

Comment: @daleif Thank you, interesting! Why have space in the individual characters instead of leaving all space decisions to the typesetting side of things?